# Room owner stats disappear after they left a room

Tags: bug, chat

The stats (like last message, count or activity plot) disappear whe the owner is not present in the chat room. This behaviour is consistent among sites.
Observed [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2710/computer-science). Plot randomly appears.
[image: Missing stats]